# How to relate friends list to user id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When using the Facebook API and calling https://graph.facebook.com/me I get an id for the logged in user, this ID as I understand is a sandboxed id of the user within my facebook app.

If I request the user's list of friends, the api retrieves a list of friends, last names and first names, and also another id. However this ID is longer in length.

How does this ID (for the friends) relate to the ID that I got originally for the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean. Have you requested the friends with `/me/friends`? If so, the IDs you're seeing are `object_ids` of type user.

Comment: me/friends is just giving me {"data":[],"summary":{"total_count":818}}

Comment: Well, then nobody of your friends is using your app. What did you request as "user's list of friends"

Comment: In the original question, I was getting the friend list using /me/taggable_friends. Which returns does return the friend list but for each contact I only have the fields id, name and picture. But the ids are long something like AaJFhaiZCUEkoucplxz3MIOdz2pxRzKe1yyN3k0acan6BhECfEob0EglCwun8SjbLDy4kIq22bObXZBC97gsraLkrN1yuEiP314B

Comment: You're using the wrong endpoint. `taggable_friends` are only to be used for tagging friends in posts. It's also subject to Facebook's Login Review, which will very likely not grant you the permission if you use it in that way. Baseline: **You cannot get all friends, only those which use your app**

Comment: Furthermore, `taggable_friends` only has a very limited set of fields: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-taggable-friend/

Comment: so, you are not even able to retrieve the whole list of friends with app-specific ids (of the same type as you get when u query /me/ and get the attribute id for the current user) ?

Comment: As I wrote, yes. And this is the case since nearly 1,5 years. Please have a look at the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog/#v2_0

Comment: I see, makes sense spam-wise I guess. Thanks for the info!